# I am getting a DB collation error when loading data

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

Hi I am loading the data from MySQL staging to MySQL destination. 
I get this error and it says Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci, COERCIBLE) and (latin1_german1_ci, COERCIBLE) for operation '='
Does this has to do anything with Pentaho. Because the same runs fine in Production server but gives error in Dev server.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not Pentaho since it is working in one area, but not another. Try:

Moving the code from your prod box to your dev box to make sure you didn't introduce any changes unintentionally.

Are your MySQL instances the same versions?  Are they supported by Pentaho?  What about your drivers?  And are the drivers all stored in the correct places?  Make sure that you don't have two of the MySQL drivers in the different folders to avoid conflicts.

Run the job in row level mode to see the most messages about what is occurring.  It could give you important clues.